# IF statement based on number count on excel

Tags: excel

How do I properly create a syntax for `IF-ELSE` statement that will insert a text?

[image]

**Scenario:**

The goal is to insert a text in `column H` based on the text from `column B`

**First rule:** If column B starts with either SB or HB, write a text like "The 2020 amendment to this section by S.B. 123"

The **S.B.** should become **H.B.** if `column B` starts with HB

So I did:

`=IF(LEFT(B2,2)="HB","The 2020 amendment to this section by H.B. "&(RIGHT(B2,4)),"The 2020 amendment to this section by S.B. ")`

The above statement is not enough. I need to insert more `IFs` for the number of digits after the **HB/SB**

So I need something if it has 4 digits, 3 digits, and 2 digits.

I tried making the first IF nested inside IF but *failed*. I did something like this:

`=IF(LEN(B2="8" and so on, insert first IF` **meaning if B2 has 8 character including the spaces**

I also tried:

`IF(B2=8) and so on, insert first IF`

I keep trying but I keep getting the error in my formula. I will really appreciate any help.

Comment: So what should it do if it starts with AB?

Comment: I'm sorry that is just a wrong one, please ignore AB. It's only for HB and SB

Comment: How many initials are there? Just HB and SB, or could there be more such as AB? I will post the answer, assuming you have just two prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these two formulas will work for you. Depends on how column B is populated and how to populate column H. Pick from one of these two:

If column B only starts with SB or HB, then use formula 1 below.

If column B has more than just SB or HB as the initials but you only want to write the language column if B starts with SB or HB, then use formula 2 below. Any other prefixes will be ignored.

Formula 1 in column H:

```
    =IF(LEFT(B2,2)="SB","The 2020 amendment to this section by S.B. "&RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2)),"The 2020 amendment to this section by H.B. "&RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND(" ",B2)))
```

Formula 2 in column H:

```
    =IF(OR(LEFT(B5,2)="SB",LEFT(B5,2)="HB"),IF(LEFT(B5,2)="SB","The 2020 amendment to this section by S.B. "&RIGHT(B5,LEN(B5)-FIND(" ",B5)),"The 2020 amendment to this section by H.B. "&RIGHT(B5,LEN(B5)-FIND(" ",B5))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Isolated, I didn't think someone would help me all the way, for this particular query. Btw, I only have HB/SB and never anything else. I just forgot to change the AB above. But please don't delete it. I'll try to learn from formula 2 as well.